# field update with formula

Tags: workflow, picklist, field-update

I have a workflow which closes a case itself if the customer hasn't returned to us after certain time. After case is closed I want to populate a field with a certain value, but only if this field is empty.
This field's type is picklist. I have a field update action defined but I cannot verify if there's already a value on this field or not.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[ISBLANK function](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#ISBLANK)** to verify if field contains any value or not.

Description : Determines if an expression has a value and returns TRUE if it does not. If it contains a value, this function returns FALSE.

Usages: **ISBLANK(expression)** and replace expression with the expression you want evaluated.

So in your case as this is picklist value your function will be like this **ISBLANK(TEXT(fieldapiname))**

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thank you for replying, but I'm afraid I wasn't clear. I have a WFR, in one of the steps I do a field update to a picklist field. I want to do this field update only if there's no value in that field already. Meaning I have the initial condition in the WFR and then I need to have another condition / use a formula for checking if the field is blank, but in the field update I don't have an option to use formula since it's a picklist field. I hope my pain is clearer now.

Comment: Why don't you add that in initial condition of WFR

Comment: since it's a time dependent WF and it was not the first action - I haven't thought about this solution. As it turns out - I took your advice. Thanks!